# $_POST returns empty array after ajax post request to php page

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to post my username and password to my php file through ajax but it post["username"] and post["password"] end up being Undefined index

I tried the following.

/index.php

```
<form action="home.php" method="POST">
<input name= "username" id="usrname" type="text" placeholder="username">
    <input name="pswrd" id="pswrd" type="password" placeholder="password">
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

/main.js

```
 $('#submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var username = $('#usrname').val();
    var pswrd = $('#pswrd').val();

    if (username === "" || pswrd === "") {

        //validation
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: "home.php",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                "username": username,
                "password": pswrd
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert('its works')
                // window.location = 'home.php';
            }
        })
    };
})
```

/home.php

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
    echo "<h2>".$username."</h2>"; 
    echo "<h2>".$password."</h2>";   
} else {    
    echo "<h2>Nothing received</h2>";   
}
print_r($_POST)
```

When I click on submit the request does get handled as it should. When I checked under 'network->preview' I get => Array ( [username] => admin [password] => admin ) but when it doesnt send me to my home.php page and when i click on the network 'home.php' it gives me "Undefined index: ... " for my username and password.

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript makes a POST request to `home.php` with some data in it.

`home.php` responds with some data consisting of some HTML subheadings and a dump of the `$_POST` variable. This is not JSON.

You told jQuery `dataType: 'json'` so it is expecting JSON. Since it didn't get it, it doesn't read the response as successful and calls `error` instead of `success`. Since you didn't define `error`, nothing happens.

---

If the request *was* successful, it would show the alert.

If you hadn't commented it out, you would then run `window.location = 'home.php'` which would trigger a **new** HTTP GET request to `home.php` and show the result.

This request would not include the POST data so `home.php` would show nothing except for some empty `<h2>` elements, some *undefined index* errors and a representation of an empty array.

---

> when i click on the network 'home.php' it gives me "Undefined index: ... " for my username and password.

This manually gives the same effect as `window.location = 'home.php';` (makes a GET request) with the same problems as described above.

---

If you want to load the results of your HTTP request as a new page then **don't use Ajax**, just use a regular form submission.

Use Ajax when you want to process the response with JS and *not* leave the current page.

Comment: Okay but i do have my error defined but i still dont get any error how can I know where the problem is? Thank you for your explantion tho!!

Comment: @Quentin I wish (someday) to become at least half as good a programmer as you.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

> data: {
>                   "username": username,
>                   "password": pswrd
>               },

To this:

> data: 'username='+username+'&password='+pswrd,

And remove this:

> dataType: 'json',

Answer (score -1):

Try change `<form action="home.php" method="POST">` to `<form action="javascript:void(0)" method="POST">`

Comment: That's a horrible hack to create an effect better achieved with `e.preventDefault();` … which the OP is already using. That won't change anything.

Answer (score -1):

Try in ajax call...`data {username:username, password:pswrd}` ... without "

Comment: That has no effect beyond saving 4 bytes of JavaScript. Object property names can be strings *or* identifiers.